# make frames and open specific buffers in succession

Tags: frames, config

im trying to launch emacs with specific named frames and want each frame to have a specific buffer opened in a specific frame (ie have the frame named `FM` opned a dired buffer at `~/~)

this is my current state of my conf to try to achieve this:

```
*** create startup frames 
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp  :results none
(set-frame-name "MAIN")
(make-frame '((name . "FM")))
(make-frame '((name . "TERM"))) 
(make-frame '((name . "ORG")))




#+END_SRC
*** binds for frames 
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp  :results none
(global-set-key (kbd "s-a") (lambda () (interactive) (select-frame-by-name "MAIN")))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-s") (lambda () (interactive) (select-frame-by-name "TERM")))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-d") (lambda () (interactive) (select-frame-by-name "ORG"))) 
(global-set-key (kbd "s-z") (lambda () (interactive) (select-frame-by-name "FM"))) 
#+END_SRC
*** open in frames 
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp  :results none
(select-frame-by-name "FM") (dired-jump  "~/")
(select-frame-by-name "TERM") (eshell)
;; initial frame
(select-frame-by-name "MAIN") (find-file "~/org/files/agenda/TODO.org")

#+END_SRC
```

the frames are indeed generated and named correctly, yet i cany get the frames to open the correct buffer. im a bit at a loss.

Comment: Here is a link to a complex example that places specific buffers in certain frames, creating new frames if one with matching a specific frame name does not exist:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame .  It works for file-visiting buffers and also non-file-visiting buffers.  It can be taken one step further by associating the buffer with the frame using a library such as frame-buffs by Alp Aker (or just the innards).

Answer (score 2):

No need to fiddle with `make-frame` or hooks at all for this.
Just use **`special-display-buffer-names`** to specify that those buffers get *dedicated frames*.

You can even give their frames particular parameters (e.g. different background colors), if you want.

For example:

```el
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      (append '(("FM"   (background-color . "LightBlue"))
                ("ORG"  (background-color . "LightGreen"))
                ("TERM" (background-color . "LightPink")))
              special-display-buffer-names))
```

Or you can use the same frame parameters for all three and just set
**`special-display-regexps`** to a regexp that matches (only) those
buffer names:

```el
(setq special-display-frame-alist
      (cons '(background-color . "LightBlue") special-display-frame-alist))
(setq special-display-regexps
      (concat "\\`" (regexp-opt '("FM" "ORG" "TERM")) "\\'"))
```

If you prefer, you can just use Customize to customize any of those options: `special-display-buffer-names`, `special-display-regexps`, and `special-display-frame-alist`.  That's generally preferable (IMO) to adding code to your init file that does the same thing.

See the Elisp manual, node [Dedicated Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html) for more info about dedicated windows.

---

Special-display buffers are a handy way to do this kind of thing.  Alternatively, you can fiddle with `display-buffer-alist` to do the same thing.

Note: Emacs considers special-display buffers "obsolete" since the more general mechanism of `display-buffer-alist` was implemented.  (And they removed all mention of special-display from the manuals -- see below.)  I don't consider special-display buffers to be obsolete or no longer useful just because you can do the same thing (and more) in a more complicated way.  And I'm very glad that Emacs Dev made sure, with some encouragement, that the special-display code and doc strings have not been removed, and everything still works just fine, as always.

---

FYI, here is the Elisp manual doc (node `Choosing Window`) about special-display buffers from Emacs 23, before they removed it:

> - User Option: **`special-display-buffer-names`**
>
>   A list of buffer names identifying buffers that should be displayed
>      specially.  If the name of `BUFFER-OR-NAME` is in this list,
>      `display-buffer` handles the buffer specially.  By default, *special
>      display means to give the buffer a dedicated frame*.
>
>   If an element is a list, instead of a string, then the `CAR` of that
>      list is the buffer name, and the rest of that list says how to
>      create the frame.  There are two possibilities for the rest of
>      that list (its `CDR`): It can be an alist, specifying frame
>      parameters, or it can contain a function and arguments to give to
>      it.  (The function's first argument is always the buffer to be
>      displayed; the arguments from the list come after that.)
>
>   For example:
>
>   `(("myfile" (minibuffer) (menu-bar-lines . 0)))`
>
>   specifies to display a buffer named `myfile` in a dedicated frame
>      with specified `minibuffer` and `menu-bar-lines` parameters.
>
>   The list of frame parameters can also use the phony frame
>      parameters `same-frame` and `same-window`.  If the specified frame
>      parameters include `(same-window . VALUE)` and `VALUE` is non-`nil`,
>      that means to display the buffer in the current selected window.
>      Otherwise, if they include `(same-frame .  VALUE)` and `VALUE` is
>      non-`nil`, that means to display the buffer in a new window in the
>      currently selected frame.
> - User Option: **`special-display-regexps`**
>
>   A list of regular expressions specifying buffers that should be
>      displayed specially.  If the buffer's name matches any of the
>      regular expressions in this list, `display-buffer` handles the
>      buffer specially.  By default, special display means to give the
>      buffer a dedicated frame.
>
>   If an element is a list, instead of a string, then the `CAR` of the
>      list is the regular expression, and the rest of the list says how
>      to create the frame.  See `special-display-buffer-names` above.
> - Function: **`special-display-p buffer-name`**
>
>   This function returns non-`nil` if displaying a buffer named
>      `BUFFER-NAME` with `display-buffer` would create a special frame.
>      The value is `t` if it would use the default frame parameters, or
>      else the specified list of frame parameters.
> - User Option: **`special-display-function`**
>
>   This variable holds the function to call to display a buffer
>      specially.  It receives the buffer as an argument, and should
>      return the window in which it is displayed.  The default value of
>      this variable is `special-display-popup-frame`, see below.
> - Function: **`special-display-popup-frame buffer &optional args`**
>
>   This function tries to make `BUFFER` visible in a frame of its own.
>      If BUFFER is already displayed in some window, it makes that
>      window's frame visible and raises it.  Otherwise, it creates a
>      frame that is dedicated to `BUFFER`.  The return value is the window
>      used to display `BUFFER`.
>
>   If `ARGS` is an alist, it specifies frame parameters for the new
>      frame.  If `ARGS` is a list whose `CAR` is a symbol, then `(car ARGS)`
>      is called as a function to actually create and set up the frame;
>      it is called with `BUFFER` as first argument, and `(cdr ARGS)` as
>      additional arguments.
>
>   This function always uses an existing window displaying `BUFFER`,
>      whether or not it is in a frame of its own; but if you set up the
>      above variables in your init file, before `BUFFER` was created, then
>      presumably the window was previously made by this function.
> - User Option: **`special-display-frame-alist`**
>
>   This variable holds frame parameters for
>     `special-display-popup-frame` to use when it creates a frame.

Comment: thx for this very comprehensive response. this looks inline with what im aiming at. though how does one launch these special-display-buffers on startup (using emacs daemon if possible) to create 4 separate frames with pre defined buffers?

Comment: You don't need to worry about creating the frames - they get created whenever you visit the buffers. If you want to create them initially, rather than interactively, just use any of `switch-to-buffer`, `pop-to-buffer`, `display-buffer`, `find-file` (if they are file buffers), `dired` (if they are directory buffers), etc. in your init file. *It's enough to display the buffer* to get it displayed in the dedicated frame you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplified example I have inserted into my `init.el` (it omits keybindings for switching to the frames):

```
;; 0. for the main frame this hook is not called
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          (lambda (frame)
            (select-frame frame)
            (cond
             ((equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) "FM")
              (dired "~/"))
             ((equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) "TERM")
              (eshell)))))

(set-frame-name "MAIN")
;; 1. that is why we need to explicitly open the file needed here
(find-file "~/org/files/agenda/TODO.org")

(make-frame '((name . "FM")))
(make-frame '((name . "TERM")))
```

So it creates 3 frames for me (default one and 2 more).

1. for the default frame you have to do "setup" right away.
2. for other frames you create in `init.el` you should(?) use `after-make-frame-functions` hook and provide what you want to do with them there.

Comment: This works great @max Kim !..but..:)..seems not to work when i launch Emacs in daemon mode. i get this error: `Unknown terminal type`. any clue why?

Comment: I am not sure. Try to remove `(find-file "~/org/files/agenda/TODO.org")`. Or maybe daemon mode has nothing to do with frames, because frames should be only created by emacsclient?